# org-present mode makes asterisk characters invisible

Tags: org-mode

My `org-mode` TODO list looks like this in Emacs:

```
*Angular
**Two way binding
***{{modelName}}
**Controller
***Do crud operations
***Different scopes across the application
```

I wanted to present it using [`org-present`](https://github.com/rlister/org-present), which I enabled by doing `M-x` `org-present`. This removed all hierarchy-related asterisks and turned the visible text into a plain list:

```
Angular
Two way binding
{{modelName}}
Controller
Do crud operations
Different scopes across the application
```

I am interested in preserving the hierarchy levels for display. How can I do that in `org-present-mode` (or any other presentation mode for Emacs)?

Additionally, I noticed that `org-present-mode` doesn't get toggled when I do `M-x` `org-present` twice.

Comment: Is this the package you mean? https://github.com/rlister/org-present. What do you want to happen when you start `org-present` mode?

Comment: yes, tat's it. Now, all contents go into 1 slide. `org-present` can split them into different slides, 1 slide for main line, 1 slide each for sub-topics from level 2. once i enable this mode, key presses are behaving strangely and i couldn't figure out how to even add an extra slide...

Comment: In the README it says that slides are divided at each level 1 header. So if you want a new slide, you just put a new level 1 header.

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, but you should get in the habit of adding a space between the last leading asterisk and the contents of a headline. That way, `org-mode` will be able to recognize and fontify your headlines properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're raising two separate issues.

#### Keeping asterisks visible

`org-present` calls `org-present-add-overlays`, which is responsible for making the leading asterisks invisible. Here is a modified version of `org-present-add-overlays` that you can add to your init-file to make sure asterisks stay visible:

```el
(defun org-present-add-overlays ()
  "Add overlays for this mode."
  (add-to-invisibility-spec '(org-present))
  (save-excursion
    ;; hide org-mode options starting with #+
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "^[[:space:]]*\\(#\\+\\)\\([^[:space:]]+\\).*" nil t)
      (let ((end (if (org-present-show-option (match-string 2)) 2 0)))
        (org-present-add-overlay (match-beginning 1) (match-end end))))
    ;; hide emphasis markers
    (let ((org-emph-re "\\([ \t('\"{]\\|^\\)\\(\\([/_=~+]\\)\\([^ \t\r\n,\"']\\|[^ \t\r\n,\"'].*?\\(?:\n.*?\\)\\{0,1\\}[^ \t\r\n,\"']\\)\\3\\)\\([- \t.,:!?;'\")}\\]\\|$\\)"))
      (while (re-search-forward org-emph-re nil t)
        (org-present-add-overlay (match-beginning 2) (1+ (match-beginning 2)))
        (org-present-add-overlay (1- (match-end 2)) (match-end 2))))))
```

#### `org-present` won't toggle `org-present-mode`

As described [here](https://github.com/rlister/org-present#configuration), there is a separate command for ending a presentation and going back to "vanilla" `org-mode`. It is called `org-present-quit`; the default binding for it is `C-c C-q`, so just hit that if you want to get out of `org-present-mode`.

Alternatively, if you want to be able to use the `org-present` command as a toggle, you can [advise](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) it as follows:

```el
(defun org-present-toggle (orig)
  (if (not org-present-mode)
      (funcall orig)
    (org-present-quit)))

(advice-add 'org-present :around #'org-present-toggle)
```

Comment: hi itsjeyd, it works well... the regex for `org-emph-re` is a bit stretchy, which raises the question.. what is considered as the boundaries of an overlay? is this regex `org-emph-re` meant to split first level headings into different overlays/slides?

Comment: @MadhavanKumar No, it's not. `org-emph-re` is used to locate and hide [emphasis markup](http://orgmode.org/manual/Emphasis-and-monospace.html) in the buffer: As you probably know, asterisks can be used to make text bold in `org-mode`. When using an unchanged version of `org-emph-re` in `org-present-add-overlays`, it *will* match asterisks that are actually part of your headlines. So in order to make sure you wouldn't lose *any* asterisks I modified the original value of `org-emph-re` to not match asterisks.